# Issue in plotting data in Python

Tags: matplotlib

I have 4 sets of datasets that when I plot in excel seems good bu when I plot it in python, my plots are so messed up. Can you help me solve the problem.

Here is my [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zKdY3v5Ram8YVwunLGFfscJymiPGpyqa/view?usp=sharing).

This is my code

```python
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

adelaide = pd.read_csv('')

# Create figure and axes
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

# Plot EVI on left y-axis and bottom x-axis
ax1.plot(adelaide['evi_time'], adelaide['Smoothed_EVI'], color='green', label='EVI')
ax1.set_xlabel('EVI Time')
ax1.set_ylabel('Smoothed EVI', color='green')

# Set y-axis limits for EVI
ax1.set_ylim(adelaide['Smoothed_EVI'].min(), adelaide['Smoothed_EVI'].max())

# Create a second x-axis on top for GPP
ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.plot(adelaide['gpp_time'], adelaide['GPP'], color='red', label='GPP')
ax2.set_xlabel('GPP Time')

# Create a second y-axis on the right for GPP
ax3 = ax1.twinx()
ax3.plot(adelaide['gpp_time'], adelaide['GPP'], color='red', label='GPP')
ax3.set_ylabel('GPP', color='red')

# Set y-axis limits for GPP
ax3.set_ylim(adelaide['GPP'].min(), adelaide['GPP'].max())

# Show plot
plt.show()
```

My plot looked like this but works fine in excel. I can fix the x axis, I need help on why my data is messing up

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]
You are overdoing. You need just two `Axes` and a single time axis.

```
# code to place your data in d0, d1 (dates) and y0, y1 (measurements)
...
#
fig, ax0 = plt.subplots()
ax1 = plt.twinx()
ax0.plot(d0, y0, color='green')
ax0.set_ylabel('Smoothed EVI', color='green')
ax1.plot(d1, y1, color='red')
ax1.set_ylabel('GPP', color='red')
```

---

In case you NEED a different time axis,

```
fig, ax0 = plt.subplots()
ax1 = ax0.twinx().twiny()
ax0.plot((0, 100), (-20, 20), color='g')
ax1.plot((-20, 20), (100, 0), color='r')
```

[image]